# Is it possible to synchronize comments of the plugin Facebook Comments and comments on the Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I have a page on the site with comments implemented by plugin Facebook Сomments https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments. Also, I have Facebook post with comments (like this - https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/)

Is it possible to synchronize comments of the plugin Facebook Сomments and comments on the Facebook post? I want to messages,   added to the Facebook post, displayed on the web page with the plugin Facebook Comments. And vice versa.

Comment: That’s called Comment Mirroring – see docs for the plugin. (Be aware though that this will only work on new URLs, after you enabled it; it will not work for URLs that you already had the plugin on before.)

Comment: CBroe, thanks for the answer. That's what I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s called Comment Mirroring – see docs for the plugin, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Be aware though that this will only work on new URLs, after you enabled it; it will not work for URLs that you already had the plugin on before.